# How to understand the beat in chisel language?

Tags: scala, cpu, riscv, chisel

I am studying the design of `riscv-Boom`. It is designed with `chisel`. When I read its source code, I always cannot understand when the signals in these circuits will be obtained. Normal programs are executed one by one. But hardware languages like chisel are not.

https://github.com/riscv-boom/riscv-boom/blob/master/src/main/scala/exu/issue-units/issue-slot.scala
For example, the link above is the source code of Issue-slot in Boom.

```
 103:  val next_uop = Mux(io.in_uop.valid, io.in_uop.bits, slot_uop)
 113:  state := io.in_uop.bits.iw_state
 126:  next_state := state
 127:  next_uopc := slot_uop.uopc
 128:  next_lrs1_rtype := slot_uop.lrs1_rtype
 129:  next_lrs2_rtype := slot_uop.lrs2_rtype
 155   slot_uop := io.in_uop.bits
 208:  for loop
```

This is some code in the IssueSlot class in the link above. For the chisel hardware language, these `:=` should mean that they are connected together by wires. So do these signals change at the same time? For example, when `io.in_uop.valid` is true, does the above code assign values at the same time?

1. For example, the current uop is fmul, and in_uop= is fadd. When io.in_uop.valid, the above code will be executed at the same time. But there is a problem.

```
origin 
     uop = fmux
when io.in_uop.valid
     103:  val next_uop = io.in_uop.bits       (fadd uop)
     113:  state := io.in_uop.bits.iw_state    (fadd state)
     126:  next_state := state                  (fmux state)
     127:  next_uopc := slot_uop.uopc             (fmux uopc)
     128:  next_lrs1_rtype := slot_uop.lrs1_rtype (fmux lrs1_rtype )
     129:  next_lrs2_rtype := slot_uop.lrs2_rtype (fmux lrs2_rtype )
     155   slot_uop := io.in_uop.bits              (faddlrs2_rtype )
     208:  for loop
```

When io.in_uop.valid is true, the transmit slot at this time will be input `fadd` information. At the same time, the original `fmul` information will still be output to next-related signals. This should be unreasonable. Where does the problem occur?

2. For the for loop of line 207. I still find it difficult to understand. Will the for loop be executed in one beat? For example, if I use a for loop to traverse a queue, when did the for loop finish?

If anyone is willing to answer me, I would be extremely grateful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. first

The `a := b` expression mean that  `b` is connected to `a` yes. `b` is the source and `a` the sink.
If a new connection to `a` is done after in the code, it will be replaced.

In the following code, `a` is connected to `c`:

```
a := b
a := c
```

This writing could be strange but it's usefull to set a default value in conditionnal branch.

For example :

```
a := b
when(z === true.B){
    a := c
}
```

By default, `a` will be connected to `b` except when `z` is true.

2. second

Do not forget that Chisel is an HDL **generator**. It generate hardware code, some keywords are pure Scala like `if`, `for`, ... and other are hardware chisel keyword like `when`, `Mux`, ...

Then the for loop in line 208 is executed at the code generation stage. And it will generate some hardware chisel `when` mux code.

Answer (score 2):

I'd highly recommend you spend some time with the [Chisel Bootcamp](https://github.com/freechipsproject/chisel-bootcamp). It can really help you grasp the generator aspects of chisel.